# How to tell browser to load new HTML/CSS/JS (prevent user need to clean his browser cache)?

Tags: apache, nginx, server, frontend

The way I use on FE side to handle this problem doesn't work always.

Sometimes depending on server settings (apache or nginx in my case) browser doesn't want to load new HTML file (in which filenames were replaced).

What I usually do is:

1) add file checksum to file name and replace links in HTML using grunt/gulp/webpack

2) add `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />` tag to HTML to tell server that it needs to serve new HTML always (not sure about this step). (this step not always works, depend on server settings)

I think there is a better less complex way to do this, by editing server config (without filenames regeneration). But don't know actually how to do this.

The perfect way is to just let the browser know that something is changed and it needs to load new stuff only. I assume this can be done through max-age server config settings.

It would be great if anyone could advice simple solution for Wordpress additionally (any plugin that handles this automatically).

It would be nice to see Apache, nginx configs examples.

Comment: Have you tried just appending an empty/dummy query string?  By default, HTTP caches are a little more sensitive if they see a query on a GET.

Comment: What do you mean by saying dummy string? filename change? 
Please read point 1) then.